# Set matplotlib rectangle edge to outside of specified width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to specify the edge for [matplotlib's Rectangle patch](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) so that the border is outside the domain specified? In photoshop, this is would be called "stroke position", for example. Allow me to illustrate with an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


# Here's my "image"
X = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

# Suppose I want to highlight some feature in the middle boxes.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax.add_patch( Rectangle((0.5, 0.5), 2, 2, fc='none', ec='r') )
plt.show()
```

This yields the following:

[image]

However, if modified the above as follows

```
ax.add_patch( Rectangle((0.5, 0.5), 2, 2, fc='none', ec='r', lw=10) )
```

I obtain the figure:

[image]

As you can see, the edge is center-positioned along the border of the domain of the Rectangle object, and so bleeds into this domain. Is it possible to force the edge border to be strictly outside the Rectangle's domain?

Comment: I think it's slightly weirder that the border line bleeds *out* of the Rectangle's domain, even. It looks to me as though the solution either way is to translate the _points_ that linewidth is specified in into the coordinates the Rectangle is being defined with (usually data coordinates, can be any Transform) and then adjust the Rectangle's `x,y`. Which is clearly a hassle. Maybe there's something in `patheffects`.

Comment: So, basically draw a bigger rectangle, and adjust `(x,y)` appropriately? I thought about something along those lines, but `linewidth` seems to be based on the current figure size, not pixels. I can't seem to find in the documentation how this is specified: it only talks about "float value in points": http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linewidth

Comment: (rummaged in `patheffects` for a bit which was informative about what Strokes can do: offsets but not, AFAICT, the kind of expansion and trapping that printing programs can do. I think adjusting the `x,y` is going to be necessary.)

Comment: There's a `points_to_pixels` method on some of the renderers, but I can't remember how you get from pixels to data-units except when printing.

Comment: This may be a limitation of the path stroking logic.  A way to get what you want may be to get what you want in a very round about way by making a filled rectangle and then clipping it with an inverted clip path.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/removing-paths-inside-polygon-td40632.html Just make the outer edge of the clip path bigger than you care, the inner edge where you want to clip the box and the make the filled rectangle where you want the outside edges of the box to go.

Comment: Thanks all. I will look into these resources when I have more time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use an `AnnotationBbox` inside of which an `AuxTransformBox` is placed. This `AuxTransformBox` would contain a proxy rectangle of the desired size. This can be made invisible (e.g. `fc='none', ec='none'`). Its only function is to scale the `AuxTransformBox` to the right size. Now the `AnnotationBbox` can be given a border of some large linewidth. If it is sitting tight against the `AuxTransformBox` the border will only start where the `AuxTransformBox` ends. To let the border fit tightly, one can set the padding `pad` to half the linewidth of the border. Since padding is given in units of fontsize, it is the fontsize which needs to be set to the linewidth and the padding to 0.5, `pad=0.5,fontsize=linewidth`. Note that it appears that a slightly larger padding of 0.52 looks nicer on the plot; in any case this can be adjusted to one's liking.

Sounds complicated, but the code is copy and pastable to be used anywhere a Rectangle would usually be used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, AuxTransformBox

# Here's my "image"
X = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

# Suppose I want to highlight some feature in the middle boxes.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest', aspect="auto")

linewidth = 14
xy, w, h = (0.5, 0.5), 2, 2
r = Rectangle(xy, w, h, fc='none', ec='gold', lw=1)

offsetbox = AuxTransformBox(ax.transData)
offsetbox.add_artist(r)
ab = AnnotationBbox(offsetbox, (xy[0] + w/2., xy[1] + h/2.),
                    boxcoords="data", pad=0.52,fontsize=linewidth,
                    bboxprops=dict(facecolor="none", edgecolor='r', 
                              lw=linewidth))
ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

[image]