# outline one element of seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

Can I put an outline around one element in a seaborn heatmap?

e.g., I want to put a yellow outline around the top-left element in this figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
index_of_element_to_outline = [0, 0]

sb.heatmap(matrix)
# insert some code to outline the given element 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a rectangle is as easy as,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
index_of_element_to_outline = [0, 0]

ax = sns.heatmap(matrix)
rect = plt.Rectangle(index_of_element_to_outline, 1,1, color="gold", 
                     linewidth=3, fill=False, clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For a more sophisticated solution, where the rectangle does not overlay the pixel it encompasses, see [Set matplotlib rectangle edge to outside of specified width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081846/set-matplotlib-rectangle-edge-to-outside-of-specified-width).