# Draw linewidth inside rectangle matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble drawing rectangles in matplotlib using Patches. When `linewidth` is supplied to patches.Rectangle, the border is drawn on the outside of the rectangle. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
rect = patches.Rectangle((1, 1), 1, 1, facecolor = 'blue')
rect2 = patches.Rectangle((1, 2.1), 1, 1, facecolor = 'none', edgecolor = 'black', linewidth = 6)
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.add_patch(rect2)

ax.set_xlim([0, 3.5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 3.5])
```

here's the result:

[image: Matplotlib rectangles]

Note that the border is drawn on the outside of the box such that the box + border now exceeds the size of the blue box. I would like the border to be drawn inside the box, such that it is always the same size as the blue box regardless of linewidth.

[image: Desired result]

I've tried this in two different ways and neither was satisfying:

1. Convert the linewidth from absolute units into units of the data, then calculate a smaller box that could be drawn with a normal border that matches the other box.
2. Explore some of the `offsetbox` functionality as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081846/set-matplotlib-rectangle-edge-to-outside-of-specified-width), though I didn't get very far as I couldn't figure out how to specify `pad` correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A pragmatic solution without extra calculations would be to add a blue border of the same width to the blue rectangle.

Comment: @JanKuiken A problem with such an approach would be that the boxes start overlapping while if the border goes inside, the padding between the boxes would stay constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach is to set a clip rectangle that hides everything outside the rectangle. As you already have a rectangle, it can be used to clip itself.

As the border is drawn centered on the border line, half of it will be clipped away. This can be tackled by setting the width to double the desired width.

Note that for clipping to work as desired, the rectangle already needs to be transformed to axes coordinates. So, first add the rectangle patch to the ax and only then use is to set the clipping.

Also note that with default parameters, a rectangle uses the same color for the inside as well as for a thin border. Setting the linewidth to zero ensures that it doesn't draw outside the rectangle.

Similarly, ellipses can be drawn with the line only at the inside.

The code below uses a thickness of 10 and some extra dotted red lines to illustrate what's happening.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pad = 0.1 # distance between the rectangles
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        x = .5 + i * (1 + pad)
        y =  .5 + j * (1 + pad)
        if i == j:
            patch = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, facecolor='blue', linewidth=0)
        elif i < 2:
            patch = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black',
                                     linewidth=10*2 if j == 0 else 10)
        else:
            patch = patches.Ellipse((x+0.5, y+0.5), 1, 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black',
                                     linewidth=10*2 if j == 0 else 10)
        ax.add_patch(patch)
        if j == 0:
            patch.set_clip_path(patch)

for i in range(3):
    x = .5 + i * (1 + pad)
    for s in 0,1:
        ax.axvline (x+s, color='crimson', ls=':', lw=1)
for j in range(2):
    y =  .5 + j * (1 + pad)
    for s in 0,1:
        ax.axhline (y+s, color='crimson', ls=':', lw=1)

ax.set_xlim([0, 4.0])
ax.set_ylim([0, 3.0])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The image below shows the standard way of drawing at the top, and clipping with double linewidth at the bottom.

[image: resulting plot]